# EXCEL VBA from a summary list to prompt for Order No. Copy all the data related to Order No to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, matching

[image: Data Sheet]

Hi,
  I am new to VBA, I had a sheet of data with an order number. I was looking for the prompt that allows me to enter multiple order number and pull all the data with matching order numbers into the new sheet. I just wanted to accept multiple order numbers using , .

Thanks and would appricate your help and leads

Regards.

Comment: You can use InputBox andhave the user input comma- or space-separated order  numbers

Comment: I tried using input box comma. but I am not getting desired output

Comment: If you edit your question and post the code you tried, and explain what problems you had with it, you're more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. May try split function on the string received  from Inputbox. Further  IF 'otder no' Is numeric may try Val function

Comment: Can you help me with the code for the split? that needs to be assigned to Inputbox.  Thanks

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SearchButton1_Click()

Dim MyValue As String
Dim NewValue() As Long
Dim Num_Values As Long
Dim i As Integer
    
MyValue = TextBox1.Value
Do Until IsNumeric(Application.Search(",", MyValue)) = False
    If IsNumeric(Application.Search(",", MyValue)) Then
        Num_Values = Num_Values + 1
        MyValue = Right(MyValue, Len(MyValue) - Application.Search(",", MyValue))
    End If
Loop

Comment: MyValue = TextBox1.Value
ReDim NewValue(Num_Values)
For i = 0 To UBound(NewValue)
    If IsNumeric(Application.Search(",", MyValue)) Then
        NewValue(i) = CLng(Left(MyValue, Application.Search(",", MyValue) - 1))
        MyValue = Right(MyValue, Len(MyValue) - Application.Search(",", MyValue))
    Else
        NewValue(i) = CLng(MyValue)
    End If
    MsgBox NewValue(i)
Next i

Comment: Call HuntRow(NewValue())

End Sub

Private Sub HuntRow(OrderArray As Variant)

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=Application.ActiveSheet)
ws2.Name = "Result Rows"

Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
Dim numSearch As Long

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(OrderArray)
    numSearch = OrderArray(i)
    
    With ws1

Comment: '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    
        '~~> I am assuming that the orders are in Col C
        '~~> if not then change C below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        With .Range("C1:C" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=numSearch
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With
    
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

Comment: '~~> Destination File
    With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If
    
        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With

Next i

End Sub

Comment: Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()


Label1.Value = "Enter the PO numbers you would like to search"

TextBox1.Value = "PO numbers here"

TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Comment: This works for me but Its not taking few values in it.. Shows required answer but is missing some of the values

Answer (score 0):

the code below should put you on the right track:

```
Sub accept()

    Dim str As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim l As Long

    str = InputBox("Please type order numbers separated by comma")

    arr = Split(str, ",")

    For l = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Cells(l + 1, 1) = arr(l)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You asked for a lead, this is your lead. Show some effort on your part if you want more help.